# How can I remove a section of an XML using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

What the script below is doing is capture the number of CPU cores on a machine.  In case the script had been run before, it deletes portions of the script that may have been left over from failed attempts, then it writes them back.

It writes the httpruntime, Processmodel along with with the maxworker threads, maxworkerthreads, maxiothreads, minworkerthreads, miniotheads, then the minfreethreads, minlocalrequestfreethreeads and then it multiples the 90 and 80 from the minfreetheads and local requestfreethreads by the number of CPU cores.

Then I want it to delete trances of the  if it exists then it writes the  structure, adding connectionmanagement, and add address along with the maxconnection string, that adds the number 200 and then multiplies the 200 times the number of CPU Cores.

Here is the code below

```
$numberOfCores = Get-WmiObject -class win32_processor | Measure-Object numberOfCores -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sum
$path = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config"
[xml]$machineConfig = Get-Content $path
$node = $machineConfig.SelectNodes("/configuration/system.web") 
$node.RemoveChild(($node.SelectSingleNode("httpRuntime"))) | Out-Null
$node.RemoveChild(($node.SelectSingleNode("processModel"))) | Out-Null
$processModelxml = $machineConfig.CreateElement("processModel")
$processModelxml.setAttribute("maxWorkerThreads",370)
$processModelxml.setAttribute("maxWorkerThreads",370)
$processModelxml.setAttribute("maxIoThreads",370)
$processModelxml.setAttribute("minWorkerThreads",50)
$processModelxml.setAttribute("minIoThreads",50)
$node.AppendChild($processModelxml) | Out-Null
$httpRuntimexml = $machineConfig.CreateElement("httpRuntime")
$httpRuntimexml.setAttribute("minFreeThreads",90 * $numberOfCores)
$httpRuntimexml.setAttribute("minLocalRequestFreeThreads",80 * $numberOfCores)
$node.AppendChild($httpRuntimexml) | Out-Null
$node = $systemnetxml.SelectSingleNode('//system.net')
$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
[xml]$systemnetxml = @"
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "$(200 * $numberOfCores)" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
"@
$machineConfig.configuration.AppendChild($machineConfig.ImportNode($systemnetxml."system.net",$true)) | Out-Null
$machineConfig.Save("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config")
```

Here is the update portion of the machine.config that this touches, and notice the extra system.nets

machine.config

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
    <processModel maxWorkerThreads="370" maxIoThreads="370" minWorkerThreads="50" minIoThreads="50" />
    <httpRuntime minFreeThreads="180" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="160" />
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="400" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="400" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

changing back to only your code, still reproduces the same section, but not it out puts "connectionManagement : connectionManagement" as i mentioned previously

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way is to remove the node from its parent:

```
[xml]$machineConfig = Get-Content $path
...
$node = $machineConfig.SelectSingleNode('//system.net')
$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering Ansgar, but it does not seem to work, I get this error

Comment: ou cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\ICastillo\Desktop\Pre - Final-Alpha3.ps1:141 char:1
+ $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//system.net')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: annot convert argument "0", with value: "System.Xml.XPathNodeList", for "RemoveChild" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode": "Cannot convert the "System.Xml.XPathNodeList" value of type 
"System.Xml.XPathNodeList" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode"."
At C:\Users\ICastillo\Desktop\Pre - Final-Alpha3.ps1:142 char:1
+ $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Comment: Line 141 is $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//system.net')
Line 142 is $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)

Comment: @IggyCastillo Obviously you need to replace `$xml` with whatever variable holds the XML object read from `machine.config`. For further help: update your question with the relevant portion of your script and the complete error message.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, now when I use this

    $node = $systemnetxml.SelectSingleNode('//system.net')
    $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)

I receive this messge

    connectionManagement : connectionManagement

So you are getting me where i need to go "THANK YOU", but what does this mean?

Comment: What do you mean "what does this mean"? It's PowerShell displaying the child node you just removed. If you don't need it, suppress the output like you already did in your question.

Comment: It prints it, but in the file it is still there in the machine.config

Comment: Did you actually *save* the modified XML back to the file?

Comment: yes, at the very end.  This is part of a much larger file, but I did not post the entire thing as the entire script works, its just this one part that is not working.

Comment: Reduce your script and XML data to the smallest sample that still demonstrates the problem, then edit your question and post both script and XML there. I'm neither psychic, nor am I going to play 20 Questions with you.

Comment: sure I will do, I didnt add everything because I didnt want to make it more difficult to read.  I will update it in a few minutes, thank you and I apologize if I have annoyed you, you are helping me tons

Comment: I dont know if you get a notification when the question is updated, but it has been updated now

Comment: please be gentle, its my first real powershell script, and while it may not be very efficient (I know I can add if/else statements and functions, but I dont know how to use them yet, and surely there are other inefficiencies) but I am learning, and you are helping me tons. thank you again.

Comment: @IggyCastillo *\*sigh\** The script you posted should throw an error in the line `$node = $systemnetxml.SelectSingleNode('//system.net')`. Is `$systemnetxml` the variable containing the XML data from the file `machine.config`? Let me answer that for you: no, it's not. So why are you trying to call `SelectSingleNode()` on this variable instead of the variable that actually has the XML data from the file `machine.config`, like I told you 7 hours ago?

Comment: This was a copy and paste after a few times editing, I'm constantly working trying to do what I can on my own then of course if I figure it out I will update and let you know, I dont want to sit idle, I want to resolve this as soon as possible.  Please dont think I did not use your method, I thank you for all of the input you have giving me and i promise I am hanging on your word.  I have updated the example above when your updated script, this was the part where when i used it, it printed "connectionManagement : connectionManagement"  as an output but still left all strings

Comment: That's because you still haven't fixed the mistake in your code despite me telling you what you need to do. Twice. Please take a look at my updated answer. Then go find a PowerShell/XML tutorial. This is my final response.

Comment: you are a saint, gentleman and a scholar, thank you so much it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much, and while you did get angry at me (I dont blame you) you still helped me and I truly appreciate it.

Thanks again